# Is it possible to run module with relative imports directly?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, relative-import

I've been using relative imports for some time and it's very comfortable in large projects, but.. is it possible to run it directly?

I know only one way with try-except:

```py
try:
    from .relative_path import Something
except ImportError:
    from relative_path import Something
```

but it raises `ModuleNotFoundError` when the imported module is in the parent or other directory.

```py
try:
    from ..relative_path import Something
except ImportError:
    from parent_directry.relative_path import Something
>>ImportError
```

I found in another question to use `python -m` but it also raises an `ImportError`.

Comment: Where are you running your script from? What is the package structure?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that.

Relative imports will only work if all modules involved are inside the same package, as recognized by the import system.

The correct thing to do is to install your project properly as a package - just write a minimal `setup.py` file (there are several examples around, or you can ask an A.I. generator for one ready for you to use), and install your project as an editable package with `pip install -e .`

Example setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="packagename",
    description="...",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    package_dir={'': 'src'}, # if there is an `src` intermdiate dir, otherwise, just skip this argument
)
```

The alternative to making a proper package - say, your Python files are standalone modules, that you just happen to want to use interdependently in a loose directory structure modified according to your mood (does it sound bad enough already? :-)  ) is to import `sys` and modify the `sys.path` variable directly: it is a plain list of strings which you can modify at will. Simply insert your parent directory at the beginning if the list, and Python will find your `.py` files there.